# Xamarin Forms Allign ImageButton to bottom

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am trying to allign my ImageButton to the bottom of my page, so I created this code:

```
<RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="MainLayout" VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Grid x:Name="GridUpperControl">
            ....
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="GridBottomControl">
            ....
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ImageButton Source="ActionButton_Continue.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                     HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0, 0, 15, 15"
                     WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="80" />
    </StackLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But here is the problem, both the stacklayouts are aligned at the top....
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using a relative layout as the outer container here. To position elements inside a relativelayout, you need to use constraints. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as Max said that you can use Constraint in RelativeLayout. I have written some code:

```
<RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <StackLayout
            x:Name="MainLayout"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Grid x:Name="GridUpperControl">
                <Button Text="btn1" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="GridBottomControl">
                <Button Text="btn2" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                              Property=Width,
                                                              Factor=0.5,
                                                              Constant=-80}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                              Property=Height,
                                                              Factor=1,
                                                              Constant=-80}"
            VerticalOptions="End">
            <ImageButton
                Margin="0,0,15,15"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HeightRequest="80"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                Source="check.png"
                WidthRequest="80" />
        </StackLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The second  stacklayout x coordinate is defined as half the width of the parent, -80, y coordinate is defined as  width of the parent, -80.

[image]